# C# windows application - want to keep my business and data layer in a seperate machine and use WCF to access it

Tags: c#, wcf

I am working on a windows application already splitted up into layers(UI, Business and Data Layers). I want to keep my business and data layer in a seperate machine, so that user need to have the UI layer installed in his machine. Is it a good idea to use the WCF web service and access my business layer and data layer through it?

Comment: WCF is an excellent choice for doing this:  Means you can put any UI onto the services, re-use the services.  WCF can also bind over TCP (which is v fast!), etc.

Comment: Without knowing any other details, yes it would be a good idea.

Comment: Actually. I would like to read the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends...

If it is only thin UI layer you want to move to a user machine and then call your services with each user action then I think it is a really bad idea. Because in this case a user has a windows application which in fact responses like a web application (of course if you think of communicating via internet not local network).  So if I were you I would better create a multi-tenant web application which uses all your already implemented business logic. Also this would prevent you from having a lot of versioning issues because you have full control of you UI application unlike with windows application when you have to deal with multiple versions of your solution or at least to implement some error handling logic to make all users upgrade to a newer version to proceed working.

However, if your application mostly work offline and there is only some logic which really needs to be common for all users then your choice should be WCF. It provides you with all the tools for securing and configuring the communication channel on the configuration level without even rebuilding your application. There are also a lot of built-in options for binding and behavior configuration.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Kumaran hi there, you didn't make any comments to my answer, just wonder if it was helpful to you? If not is there is anything I can do to help you with your question?

Answer (score 0):

using wcf is an excellent idea and it will work really well but maintaining the software and keep it up to date on multiple machines will become a problem as the number of clients keep growing.....   if you are are working in a local network maybe you should consider installing the app on a terminal server and connect via rdp sessions or you could just create a web version of your UI